# Spark Scala: Add 10 days to a date string (not a column)

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a date and want to add and subtract 10 days to it. Start_date and end_date are dynamic variables from one table and will be used to filter another table.

eg.

```
val start_date = "2018-09-08"
val end_date   = "2018-09-15"
```

I want to use the two dates above in a filter shown below;

```
myDF.filter($"timestamp".between(date_sub(start_date, 10),date_add(end_date, 10)))
```

The functions date_add and date_sub only take in columns as an input. How can I add/subtract 10 (this is an arbitrary number) from my dates?

Thanks

Comment: You can just use the `java.time` package _(from **Java 8**)_. Or use the [`lit` **function**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@lit(literal:Any):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) to create a column from your values.

Comment: Thanks @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you Luis! Your solution worked, for anyone interested the solution looks like;

```
val start_date = lit("2018-09-08")
val end_date   = lit("2018-09-15")
myDF.filter($"timestamp".between(date_sub(start_date, 10),date_add(end_date, 10)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way...If you can create a temp view, then you can access the `vals` using $ interpolation.
You should make sure the format is of default ones for date/timestamp.

Check this out:

```
scala> val start_date = "2018-09-08"
start_date: String = 2018-09-08

scala> val end_date   = "2018-09-15"
end_date: String = 2018-09-15

scala> val myDF=Seq(("2018-09-08"),("2018-09-15")).toDF("timestamp").withColumn("timestamp",to_timestamp('timestamp))
myDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [timestamp: timestamp]

scala> myDF.show(false)
+-------------------+
|timestamp          |
+-------------------+
|2018-09-08 00:00:00|
|2018-09-15 00:00:00|
+-------------------+


scala> myDF.createOrReplaceTempView("ts_table")


scala> spark.sql(s""" select timestamp, date_sub('$start_date',10) as d_sub, date_add('$end_date',10) d_add from ts_table """).show(false)
+-------------------+----------+----------+
|timestamp          |d_sub     |d_add     |
+-------------------+----------+----------+
|2018-09-08 00:00:00|2018-08-29|2018-09-25|
|2018-09-15 00:00:00|2018-08-29|2018-09-25|
+-------------------+----------+----------+


scala>
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative solution